# Canceling alarm manager when service has finished

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-pendingintent

I want to cancel my alarm-manager, which starts a service, and which I created using following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CheckStatusService.class);
pintent =  PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
cal.add (Calendar.MINUTE,1);
alarm = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60*1000, pintent);
```

I am doing

```
alarm.cancel(pintent)
```

and it is not throwing any errors, but the service I started using this Alarmmanager still continues to work.

Once the service is finished, it sends out a broadcast to one of my activities. There it is definitively received, even alarm.cancel() is called, but the service still continues to run.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see if your alarm is still scheduled. Also, are you sure that you are creating the same sort of `PendingIntent` for your `cancel()` call as you are for your `setRepeating()` call? I ask, because you are not showing where you are creating `pIntent` for `cancel()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your reply! I am not re-creating pIntent when canceling the alarm, but I am using the originally created pintent (it's a global variable in the activity). I know that the service is still running because onhandleIntent is still called (using Log.e(TAG, message)).

Comment: "I am not re-creating pIntent when canceling the alarm, but I am using the originally created pintent (it's a global variable in the activity)" -- then `pIntent` could be `null`, if the process was terminated in between runs of your app. Beyond that, please use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to confirm that *this alarm* is what is causing `onHandleIntent()` to get called, versus some other alarm from previous development that did not get cancelled. Also, if you are going to use a `_WAKEUP` alarm, use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` or my `WakefulIntentService`, not just a bare `IntentService`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by cancelling the alarm within the service by using the following code:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CheckStatusService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager.cancel(pintent);
```